# Magento 2: Google Recaptcha is not showing in Login page

Tags: magento2.3, login, magento2-enterprise, recaptcha

I have enabled the Google Recaptcha in Login and Register via admin panel configuration using the API Site and Secret keys. But the Google Recaptcha is not showing in Login page though its showing in register page without any issues.

[image]

So, I have switched the theme to default Luma them and seen that the Google Recaptcha is showing in the Login page as well. I'm clear now the problem is coming from theme level updates but I'm not sure where I need to check.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see the following file and check in that if something related to login form is override there or not, sometimes login form in custom theme never call the other blocks or container like "form_additional_info"

**app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml**

Comment: Thanks. I got the solution